# Regular Expression Format Confusion

Tags: compilation, expression, regular-language, formal-languages

I'm trying to get my head around some regular expression to later program a compiler.

if I have the expression:

(a or b)*

Is this the same as a* or b*? Or does it mean that you can choose a or b zero or more times.

For example, using this regular expression, can I generate {ababababa} or only strings of {aaaaaaa} or {bbbbbbb}? If the input symbol is a b then does that mean only the b can occur zero or more times or can a occur the second time too?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most regex libraries, the `or` operator is spelled <kbd>|</kbd>, so your regex would be `(a|b)*`.

That indeed means "any string of any length (including 0) made up only of <kbd>a</kbd>s and <kbd>b</kbd>s". In other words, the parentheses work just as in any algebraic expression, to define a subexpression: the <kbd>*</kbd> (postfix) operator is applied to the subexpression `a|b`.

Interesting fact: `(a*b*)*` is exactly the same set of strings as `(a|b)*`.